# if statement still outputting code despite not being true

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

The code wrapped by `<?php if(have_rows('image_slideshow')): ?>` is still being output despite there being no rows, i.e. no data in the `image` or `centered_text` field. How can I structure this if statement, so that the code is only outputted when either or both the image and centered fields have data?

```
<?php if(have_rows('image_slideshow')): ?>
    <div class="section-intro">
        <div class="slides owl-carousel">
            <?php while( have_rows('image_slideshow') ): the_row();
                $image = get_sub_field('image');
                $content = get_sub_field('centered_text'); 
            ?>
            <div class="slide intro" 
            <?php if(!empty($image)): ?>
                style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image['url']; ?>')" 
            <?php endif; ?>
            >
                <?php echo $content; ?>
            </div>           
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is 'image_slideshow'?? It is not a variable. It is a mere string. How can you put that into an apparently function have_rows()... to verify a mere string that it has rows? It is simply and always true.

It should be:

```
<?php if(have_rows($variable_that_contains_the_rows)):?>
```

Or this more straightforward way:

```
<?php if(count((array) $variable_that_contains_the_rows)): ?>
```

**I add this after a while:**

```
<?php if(count((array) have_rows('image_slideshow'))): ?>
```

Comment: I don't know wordpress nor ACF, but from the manual [have_rows()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/): `have_rows($field_name, $post_id);` -> _$field_name: the name of the repeater / flexible content field to loop through. eg “gallery_images” (required)_. Usage: `if( have_rows('parent_field') ):[...]`

Comment: Alright. Then it should be the function have_rows('image_slideshow', $the_id_of_the_slideshow)

Comment: _`$post_id`: Specific post ID where your value was entered. **Defaults to current post ID (not required)**._ I'm not sure...

Comment: It might be a slideshow in the page, not the current post nor the page.

Comment: FirstOne ... You every time add ( I don't know nothing about WordPress ) ... why You even comments this posts then ? :)